# What VS-code extension is adding these non-text lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In this screenshot, you can see the effects of two VS-Code plugins: `AlanWalk.markdown-toc` and `TomasHubelbauer.vscode-markdown-todo`, but the lines I have highlighted are effects from some other plugin I believe..

Unfortunately this effect has a negative impact because it is making the current line jump around: every time I do something like save or undo/redo, it is like someone is pressing `control+down-arrow`.

[image]

The complete list of extensions I am running is below.

```
adammaras.overtype
AlanWalk.markdown-toc
alefragnani.Bookmarks
alefragnani.copy-word
eamodio.gitlens
ego-digital.vscode-powertools
Fr43nk.seito-openfile
geddski.macros
ivangabriele.vscode-git-add-and-commit
jack89ita.copy-filename
jmfirth.vsc-space-block-jumper
johnstoncode.svn-scm
mads-hartmann.bash-ide-vscode
maximus136.change-string-case
mdickin.markdown-shortcuts
mishkinf.goto-next-previous-member
ms-mssql.mssql
mushan.vscode-paste-image
PKief.markdown-checkbox
redhat.java
ryu1kn.partial-diff
seanmcbreen.MDTools
sensourceinc.vscode-sql-beautify
Shan.code-settings-sync
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced
slevesque.vscode-autohotkey
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
TomasHubelbauer.vscode-markdown-todo
tomoki1207.vscode-input-sequence
Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here
usernamehw.remove-empty-lines
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
xyz.local-history
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is the line jumping: I thought the non-text lines were a symptom of that. Seems I am wrong about that.

It never occurred to me that it might be two extensions.. I see the line jumping behaviour when I have these two extensions enabled together `yzhang.markdown-all-in-one` and `AlanWalk.markdown-toc`

And I can prevent this negative side-affect in `AlanWalk.markdown-toc` by un-ticking "Auto update on save".

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, those non-text lines are [code lenses](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_reference-information). You can hide them by setting `"editor.codeLens": false`